# Regex for steam-like urls

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have no idea how I can build a regex to solve my needs. I can't understand this dark art so I need your helps to solve my problem.

I would like to find an url in string by using regex pattern. How can I find this type urls in a string?

> Lorem ipsum **foo://bar1234** dolor sit amet.

It should take string from foo:// until it hits a whitespace. bar1234 part is complete random and it can contain numbers, letters or special characters so I don't need any rules here. How can I do that?

I built a pattenr from some kind of pattern-creator app and from https example but it seems it doesnt work. `^(foo?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$`

Comment: @kaveman sorry I've just forgot add my trial. Its really complex for me so I can't be sure what part is wrong.

Comment: what programming language? javascript?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger yes javascript.

Comment: just a tip for the future: add a tag for your programming language too ... .net regex for example has more functions than js..

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger I was thinking all of them are same. I will add javascript tag right now

Comment: similar but some programming languages expand functionality of it so you have more functions to define your patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just keep it simple and use:

```
/\bfoo:\/\/\S+/g
```

[Check RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX9jX3/2)

Which means first match literal `foo://` using word boundaries and then match `\S+` (1 or more non-space characters).

Comment: Thank you, its working! But what is the difference between Happy pea's one, it looks shorter. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just kept it little longer to safeguard the match in order to avoid matching `abcfoo://` However `(?=\s|$)` can be safely taken out (see updated one)

Answer (score 1):

```
foo:\/\/(\S+)
```

this should do what you ask for if the formating is as simple as you say.

To test this kind of things you can always use a site like https://regex101.com/ wich should make your testing easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from foo:

```
foo:\/\/([^\s]+)
```

If you also want to keep foo in the regex:

```
(foo:\/\/[^\s]+)
```

Comment: `foo:\/\/([^\s]+)` is no different from `foo:\/\/(\S+)`

Comment: True but I wrote both cases - keeping foo:// on the regex or not, depending  on what he wants to achieve in the end